# Home page for 3d Analyze

Tags: pc, emulation, 3d-analyze

I want to try 3d Analyze to see if it can get Battlefield 2 working for me.

When I Google 3d Analyze I get a thousand mirror sites.  Not one of them looks like the actual "Home Page" of 3d Analyze.

I have found that going through mirror sites gets you old versions and spyware.

Does anyone know where I can go to get to the Home page of 3d Analyze?

Comment: What is 3d Analyze supposed to do for you?

Comment: @StrixVarina Lets you fake out the game you are trying to play.  Lets you make it think your graphics card is different that it is.

Comment: @Downvoter - I would love to know why my question was not to your liking.  Please read the FAQ and let me know which of the criteria for a good question it did not meet.

Comment: @Strix from what I understand it's a graphics card emulator - allows you to use a strong computer to run old games even if those games require a graphics card the new computer doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's http://www.tommti-systems.de/start.html.